# Realación Many to Many Doctrine2 en Symfony 3.1.3

Tags: sql, symfony3, symfony, doctrine2, doctrine

Tengo problemas al insertar los datos en la tabla, dada la relación de muchos a muchos (*many-to-many*) de mis entidades `UnidadBasica` y `Departamento`. No acepta más de dos datos, en cuanto inserto la tercera me da este error:

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Departamento", inversedBy="unidadbasica", cascade="persist")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="ub_dpto",
 *     joinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="unidadbasica_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * },
 *     inverseJoinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="departamento_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * }
 *     )
 */
protected $departamentos;

/**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="UnidadBasica", mappedBy="departamentos")
 */
protected $unidadbasica;
```

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO unidad_basica (NombreUB, Direccion, Municipio, DireccionLAN, DireccionWAN, TipoUB) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["asdad", "adasdf", "Santiago de Cuba", "10.30.1.39", "10.30.1.40", 2]:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '2' for key 'UNIQ_FBFAFE97C5555B52'

Necesito que me ayuden en esto. ¿Por qué ocurre y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: ¿Tienes una condición de unicidad (_unique constraint_) en el campo TipoUB?

Comment: no parece un problema del manytomany, sino mas bien de un unique en la tabla unidad_basica. Puedes publicar el codigo de la entidad unidad_basica? me da que el problema esta ahi.

Comment: gracias, ya me habia dado cuenta, es que tenia el campo TipoUB con ralacion OnetoOne, y realmente era ManytoOne, obviamente nunca me dejaria insertar mas de un campo...